# The signal and slot within custom class including PyQt QWidget not working

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have some trouble customizing a class including a `QPushButton` and `QLabel`, and I just want to set the `QPushButton` checkable and define a slot to its toggled signal, in addition, the custom class inherents `QObject`.

The code is shown below,

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QObject


class CustomButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, label='', parent=None):
        super().__init__(label, parent)
        self.setCheckable(True)
        self.toggled.connect(self.update)

    def update(self, state):
        if state:
            self.setStyleSheet('background-color: green')
        else:
            self.setStyleSheet('background-color: red')

class ButtonCtrl(QObject):
    def __init__(self,  parent=None, label=''):
        super().__init__()
        if isinstance(parent, QLayout):
            col = QVBoxLayout()
            parent.addLayout(col)
        else:
            col = QVBoxLayout(parent)
        self.text = ['ON', 'OFF']
        self.label = QLabel(label)
        self.button = QPushButton('ON')
        # self.button = CustomButton('ON')
        col.addWidget(self.label)
        col.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.setCheckable(True)
        self.button.setChecked(True)
        self.button.toggled.connect(self.update)
        self.update(True)
        self.label.setFont(QFont('Microsoft YaHei', 14))
        self.button.setFont(QFont('Microsoft YaHei', 12, True))
        self.button.toggle()

    # @pyqtSlot(bool)
    def update(self, state):
        if state:
            self.button.setText(self.text[0])
            self.button.setStyleSheet('background-color: green')
        else:
            self.button.setText(self.text[-1])
            self.button.setStyleSheet('background-color: red')


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        # set the layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        but = ButtonCtrl(layout, "Test")
        #self.but = ButtonCtrl(layout, "Test")
        btn = CustomButton()
        layout.addWidget(btn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    main = Window()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have customized two buttons, named `CustomButton(QPushButton)` and `ButtonCtrl(QObject)`, and I have tested the slot in the main window, however the background update slot works for `CustomButton(QPushbutton)` and does not work for `ButtonCtrl(QObject)`, the slot function is not even invoked.

However, if I change the button member of `ButtonCtrl(QObject)` from `QPushButton` into my `CustomButton(QPushButton)`, the it will work well in the main window. Furthermore, if the `but` in main window becomes a member of the main window class by setting `self.but=ButtonCtrl(layout, "Test")`, it will work as well.

I didn't find direct answer to it in Qt documentation which explains that

> Signals are emitted by an object when its internal state has changed in some way that might be interesting to the object's client or owner. Signals are public access functions and can be emitted from anywhere, but we recommend to only emit them from the class that defines the signal and its subclasses.

I am not sure if the lifetime of the `but` causing this effect, hope to get an answer, thank you.

Comment: `but = ButtonCtrl(layout, "Test")` in your `__ini__` is a local variable...so it will get garbage collected...which means but.update won't exist anymore...

Comment: Note that you shouldn't overwrite functions like `update`, since they already exist and you might need them sometime. Until you get more experienced with classes, always check for the their documentation and all the classes they inherit from (in this case, QPushButton -> QAbstractButton -> QWidget -> QObject). In any case, the rule of thumb is that if a function name is too simple/generic, another function with the same name might already exist, and it could do something else which might be needed by you or, worse, by the class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple: The ButtonCtrl class object has a local scope so it will be destroyed, and why doesn't the same happen with the CustomButton class object? Well, because the ownership of a QWidget has its parent, and the parent of that button is the window, instead the ButtonCtrl object does not have it. In this case the solution is to extend the life cycle of the variable, and in the case of a QObject there are several options:

- make the class member variable,
- Place it in a container with a longer life cycle, or
- establish a QObject parent with a longer life cycle.

Using the third alternative is just to change to:

```
class ButtonCtrl(QObject):
    def __init__(self,  parent=None, label=''):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # ...
```

The first option is the one commented on in your code:

```
self.but = ButtonCtrl(layout, "Test")
```

and the second is similar:

```
self.container = list()
but = ButtonCtrl(layout, "Test")
self.container.append(but)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's quite clear for me to understand it.